# Post item form IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I have a view who's model is of type IEnumerable:

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
```

and in this view I show a list of customers:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstnames)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>         
        <td>                       
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

However, clicking Edit puts the selected customer id on the URL and calls the [HttpGet] Edit action.

This approach means anybody can simply change the id parameter on the URL to read someone else's data.

How do I change this so that clicking Edit "Posts" the customer id to a an action method such as below?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetForEdit(int id)
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", id);
    }
```

Comment: You could wrap the table in a form, and set the form to POST back.

Comment: Changing it to a POST does nothing to solve that - anyone can post any value they want. Its you controller code which needs to validate the data - if the current user has permission to edit the `Customer`, then return the edit view, but if not, then throw an error. But why are your displaying links to a user that they should not be navigating to them anyway

Comment: I'm not displaying links to a user they're not entitled to see. But am concerned they could change the URL to access users they are not entitled to see.

Comment: Changing to a post method would allow me to ensure they can't alter the value being posted to the server. Otherwise, on clicking edit, the controller code to retrieve the customer becomes a lot more complex because it has to ensure the user is entitled to see that customer.

Comment: Changing it to a POST does not _ensure they can't alter the value being posted to the server._! (any one can use fiddler to post whatever value they want). You **MUST** always validate on the server